# I can't use any GRASS tool, I get the error "The following layers were not correctly generated"

Tags: qgis, grass-gis

I've been trying to use GRASS `r.fill.dir` to get a filled DEM but I get the error:

```
The following layers were not correctly generated.
```

I tried using SAGA Fill Sinks, that worked. I get the same error on every GRASS tool I use.

*QGIS version 3.12.0-București*